# Verify submission using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm bulding a website that allows users to upload a picture and then get the EXIF info shown in a user-friendly way.

I also want to make available an option for users to be able to share their picture online.

At the moment I already have the JavaScript for the image preview fully working: I select an Image on a Form and it appears on the website...

Now, after the users load the picture into the preview area a button appears that allows the user to upload the picture.

The thing is that I want the upload to be done without the page refreshing...

I've already asked a question about it and it has been solved by using this bit of code on the "head" of my main page, where the form is:

```html
<script> 
            // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
                $('#form1').ajaxForm(function() { 
                    alert("Image uploaded!"); 
                }); 
            }); 

</script>
```

This does work... When I press the button to upload the picture it does get uploaded, it stays on page with the preview still on sight and an alert message is shown saying "Image uploaded"..

The problem is that, in case i choose like a ".txt" file and press to upload it will still say "Image uploaded", even though it hasn't uploaded it, because on the PHP file I'm verifying the file type before uploading it, only allowing .png and .jpg...

It will also say "image uploaded" even if I modify my PHP file on purpose with wrong info... So, basically. it's not testing anything atm...

I also had my PHP coded to show a message in this situation saying "Only jpeg and png allowed..."... But this would be shown on a blank "after submiting"-page of course, which I don't want...

**The question is:
As that bit of code that uses Ajax kinda "overrides" the error messages present on my PHP code, how do I modify it in order to show an error message in case it isn't an image that's trying to be uploaded?**

Another way could be for me to verify if it's an image when loding it to the preview-area via JavaScript maybe?

My JavaScript code to load the image into a "preview area":

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            //Mostrar a imagem e o mapa ao fazer o upload
            var x = document.getElementById("itens");
            if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
            var y = document.getElementById("exif");
            if (window.getComputedStyle(y).display === "none") {
                y.style.display = "block";  


            }
            y.scrollIntoView(true); //Redireciona o ecrã para a imagem carregada    

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

        var botao = document.getElementById("upload_img");

        var z = document.getElementById("link_foto");

        botao.onclick = function() {
            if (window.getComputedStyle(z).display === "none") {
                z.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
```

My PHP code to upload the image to a folder and database:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","geopic") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link)); //ligação à base de dados e à tabela

 // O array global PHP $_FILES permite o upload de imagens do computador para o servidor.
 $image = $_FILES["imgInp"]["name"];

 //devolve o nome da cópia temporária do ficheiro presente no servidor 
 $uploadedfile = $_FILES['imgInp']['tmp_name'];

 //Devolve o tipo de ficheiro
 $image_type =$_FILES["imgInp"]["type"];

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {

     //imagecreatefrompng — Cria uma nova imagem a partir do ficheiro porque não se sabe se o utilizador vai fazer o upload de um ficheiro com extensão permitida 
 if($image_type=='image/png' || $image_type=='image/x-png')
 {
  $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
 }
 elseif($image_type=='image/gif')
 {
  $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
 }
 elseif($image_type=='image/jpeg' || $image_type=='image/jpg' || $image_type == 'image/pjpeg')
 {
  $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
 }else{
     //se não for uma imagem mostra a mensagem e termina o script
     exit ("Only jpeg and png allowed..." ) ; 
 }

 //getimagesize() Esta função vai "buscar" o tamanho da imagem carregada. O tamanho original é necessário para realizar o "resize" na função"imagecopyresampled".
 list($origWidth,$origHeight)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

    $maxWidth = 1280; //Define a largura máxima da imagem a guardar no servidor
    $maxHeight = 800; //Define a altura máxima da imagem a guardar no servidor

 if ($maxWidth == 0)
    {
        $maxWidth  = $origWidth;
    }

    if ($maxHeight == 0)
    {
        $maxHeight = $origHeight;
    }

    // Calcula a rácio dos tamanhos máximos desejados e originais
    $widthRatio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;
    $heightRatio = $maxHeight / $origHeight;

    // Rácio usada para calcular novas dimensões da imagem
    $ratio = min($widthRatio, $heightRatio);

    // Calcula as novas dimensões da imagem
    $new_width  = (int)$origWidth  * $ratio;
    $new_height = (int)$origHeight * $ratio;    


 // Função que serve para a imagem não perder qualidade perante o redimensionamento
    $image_p=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);

 // No caso da imagem ser PNG com fundo transparente, esta função mantém a transparência
    imagealphablending($image_p, false);
    imagesavealpha($image_p, true);
 //Função que vai redimensionar a imagem
    imagecopyresampled($image_p,$src,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$origWidth,$origHeight);

 //Vai gerar um nome para a foto com base na hora atual, para nunca existirem fotos com o mesmo nome

 $temp = explode(".", $image);
 $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);

 $filepath = "http://localhost/geoPic/photos/".$newfilename;

// A função move_uploaded_file vai realizar o carregamento da foto para a pasta.  
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgInp"]["tmp_name"], "photos/".$newfilename))
 {
     /*
     $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO photo (name, path) VALUES (:name, :path)");
     $stmt->bindParam(':name', $nome);
     $stmt->bindParam(':path', $caminho);

// insert one row
     $nome = $newfilename;
     $caminho = $filepath;
     $stmt->execute();

     */

    $query_image = "insert into photo (name, path) values ('".$newfilename."', '".$filepath."')";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $query_image)){
        //$link_foto = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT path FROM carro WHERE name = $newfilename");

        echo "Image uploaded";

    }else{
        echo "image not uploaded";
    }
 }
 }

?>
```

Thanks in advance..

You guys are awesome and have already provided me with crucial help in this project's development!

Comment: Sounds like it would be worth reviewing the basics of how AJAX works. This doesn't directly answer your question but it should give you enough understanding to figure out the answer on your own: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494

Comment: @cjc

Yes, I do greatly agree that I should... not review them, but LEARN them actually... It's sad, but as this project has it's foundations on a lot of self-learning it's been a path full of obstacles..

The problem is that I have a date to finish it and it's getting closer...

At the moment I really only need to finish this part and the part where I need to get the image path from the database after submiting it... after that is all about refining and safety issues

Comment: It sounds like you specifically need to make use of the ajax ``success: function(data) {}`` callback. Take that alert out of the head of your html. When data of any sort comes back from your ajax call, it will be passed as variable "data" to your success callback. Depending upon the content of the data, you can choose to trigger your alert, or do something else.

Comment: @GrantNoe

Sorry if I sound stupid, but how and where would I implement it?

Comment: Check this out: https://riptutorial.com/jquery/example/30084/jquery-ajax---success--error--vs---done-----fail--

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem(s):

1. You should add `success` property in your ajax code so that message will only be displayed when the data is processed successfully with no errors. You can apply this by replacing your code with this:

```
<script> 
            // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
                $('#form1').ajaxForm({
                   success: function(response){ alert(response); }
                }); 
            }); 

</script>
```

So after adding the script above, you need to modify your back-end to `return` a response. So in your PHP code, you should modify your code and replace `echo` with `return` so that the response will be returned to the front-end, then you can alert the response

2. I think you should ensure from the front-end (HTML) that only images with the extensions you want can be selected which i think will make it verification a lot more easier for you. You can apply this by appending an `accept` attribute to the input element (i.e. the one you used for selecting the images).

Example: `<input accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png">`

The code above will ensure that users can only select/upload files with the following extensions (jpg, jpeg, & png).

3. If you want to use JavaScript to verify if the file selected is an image, then i think you should replace your `readURL` function with this:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            const fileType = input.files[0]['type'];
            const imageTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
            if(imageTypes.includes(fileType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            //Mostrar a imagem e o mapa ao fazer o upload
            var x = document.getElementById("itens");
            if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
            var y = document.getElementById("exif");
            if (window.getComputedStyle(y).display === "none") {
                y.style.display = "block";  


            }
            y.scrollIntoView(true); //Redireciona o ecrã para a imagem carregada    

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          } else { alert("Please select a valid image"); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to implement the Ajax part.

About the "input accept"... I know it'll work, but is there an easy way to make it via JavaScript? 

I would prefer to make it that way as I'll need to make a presentation of this project and using that kind of front-end verification doesn't always "look" good...

Comment: Ok... I've tested the AJAX bit you shared and it doesn't work. It still shows the "Image uploaded" no matter if it actually uploads it or not

Comment: Ok, i know why it's not working, i will update my answer